# How can I make hyper link html tag to be a trigger for intercom

Tags: javascript, html, intercom

I have a site which is already installed intercom and it works well.

I want for intercom to act when I click a hyper link. like below.
I found the [docs](https://docs.intercom.com/install-on-your-product-or-site), but I couldn't find any hint. Is it possible? if possible, what should I do?

[image]

Comment: I found [intercom javascript docs](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/intercom-javascript). `Intercom('show');` is work.